# What was said by swami Vivekananda about Hinduism in Chicago Speech?

Tags: vivekananda

He has given a great speech about Hinduism and makes feel proud of us on our culture and Hinduism. I have only always one thing in his that speech "All my dear Brothers and Sisters". I didn't hear anything else.

Here, I just want some brief description of his speech.

Comment: Why ask such an obvious question easily available from google ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually many addresses which were given by Swami Vivekananda at Chicago. The one that you're referring to was given on September 11, 1893.

You can download [this PDF](http://www.advaitaashrama.org/Content/Download/FreeBooks/Chicago%20Addresses.pdf). It contains the addresses.

> **Chicago, 11 September 1893**
>
> Sisters and Brothers of America, It fills my heart with joy
>   unspeakable to rise in response to the warm and cordial welcome which
>   you have given us. I thank you in the name of the most ancient order
>   of monks in the world; I thank you in the name of the mother of
>   religions; and I thank you in the name of the millions and millions of
>   Hindu people of all classes and sects. My thanks, also, to some of the
>   speakers on this platform who, referring to the delegates from the
>   Orient, have told you that these men from far
>   -off nations may well claim the honour of bearing to different lands the idea of toleration. I am proud to belong to a religion which has
>   taught the world both tolerance and  universal  acceptance.  We 
>   believe  not  only  in  universal toleration, but we accept all
>   religions as true. I am proud to belong to a nation which has
>   sheltered the persecuted and the refugees of all religions and all
>   nations of the earth. I am proud to tell you that we have gathered in
>   our bosom the purest remnant of the Israelites, who came to southern
>   India and took refuge with us in the very year in which their holy
>   temple was shattered to pieces by Roman tyranny . I am proud to belong
>   to the religion which  has  sheltered  and  is  still  fostering  the 
>   remnant  of  the grand Zoroastrian nation. I will quote to you,
>   brethren, a few lines from a hymn which I remember to have repeated
>   from my earliest boyhood, which is every day repeated by millions of
>   human beings:   As the different streams having their sources in
>   different places all mingle their water in the sea, so, O Lord, the
>   different paths which men take through different tendencies, various 
>   though  they  appear ,  crooked  or  straight,  all  lead  to Thee.
>    The present convention, which is one of the most august assemblies
>   ever held, is in itself a vindication, a declaration to the world, of
>   the wonderful doctrine preached in the  Gita : Whosoever comes to Me,
>   through whatsoever form, I reach him; all men are struggling  through 
>   paths  which  in  the  end  lead  to  Me. 2 Sectarianism, bigotry,
>   and its horrible descendant, fanaticism, have long possessed this
>   beautiful earth. They have filled the earth with violence,  drenched 
>   it  often  and  often  with  human  blood, destroyed civilization, and
>   sent whole nations to despair . Had it not been for these horrible
>   demons, human society would be far more  advanced  than  it  is  now .
>   But  their  time  is  come;  and  I fervently hope that the bell that
>   tolled this morning in honour of this convention may be the
>   death-knell of all fanaticism, of all persecutions  with  the  sword 
>   or  with  the  pen,  and  of  all uncharitable feelings between
>   persons wending their way to the same goal.

Answer (score 2):

In 1893 Swami Vivekananda delivered his historical addresses at the Parliament of the World's Religions, Chicago. Six of those lectures have been included in the Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda. All those six lectured can read without any restriction at [Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_1/Addresses_at_The_Parliament_of_Religions) and few other websites.

Swami Vivekananda Quotes From The Parliament Of The World's Religions, Chicago Addresses 1893: [Source](http://www.swamivivekanandaquotes.org/2013/11/swami-vivekananda-quotes-from.html)

Chicago Speeches Of Swami Vivekananda by voice: [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGxEgLod7aQ)

Answer (score 1):

[His own voice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WIOtnn6meWA) message of peace from religion of a poor country delivered to a rich nation exactly 108 years before violence was delivered there.