# Are the text and/or speeches of Swami Vivekananda in English written by himself?

Tags: vivekananda

I know **Swami Vivekananda** gave a speech in [Chicago 1893](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26923/what-was-said-by-swami-vivekananda-about-hinduism-in-chicago-speech), I assume it was in English or was it translated to American audience. I am reading the complete works of Swami Vivekananda from [Holybooks.com](https://holybooks.com/complete-works-of-swami-vivekananda/).
If he educated himself in English, which institutions was he educated from?

Comment: Metropolitan School & General Assembly's Institution (present day Scottish Church College) of Kolkata.

Comment: At his time all the universities taught in English. It was required. A better source for his talks and writings is here - https://advaitaashrama.org/cw/

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Thank you, I will go thru the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon researching more about Swami Vivekananda, link provided by @SwamiVishwananda, I have come to understand that he is very well read in English also, could be a pundit in Bangla by default. Hence all his English speeches and writings are of his own.

Also this link provides more evidence of his [schooling and university](https://wbchse.nic.in/html/swami_vivekananda.html).

> In 1879, Narendra passed matriculation and entered Presidency College,
> Calcutta. After one year, he joined the Scottish Church College,
> Calcutta and studied philosophy. He studied western logic, western
> philosophy and history of European nations. As he advanced in his
> studies, his thinking faculty developed. Doubts regarding existence of
> God started to arise in Narendra's mind. This made him associate with
> the Brahmo Samaj, an important religious movement of the time, led by
> Keshab Chandra Sen. But the Samaj's congregational prayers and
> devotional songs could not satisfy Narendra's zeal to realise God.

It appears to me that upper class family in India adopted to learn and educate themselves in English.